# Section number and name in italics

Tags: sectioning, formatting

Note that I "inherited" a preamble that I would like to adapt:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt} % for upper line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt} % for lower line
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\itshape \nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\itshape \nouppercase \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\numberwithin{equation}{section} % numbering according to the section
\bibliographystyle{plain} %Choose a bibliograhpic style

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

%\parindent0em
\parskip1ex
```

Withe the above preamble, whenever I make new section, ie.,`\section{My Section}`, both the section number and the text `My Section` are displayed regularly. To make the text in italics, I put it in `\textit{My Section}`. This way, however, does not make the section number in italics. What should I change in order for the section number and name to always be in italics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
%                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}% DELETED
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\itshape}}% ADDED
\makeatother
```

Comment: Or `\usepackage{sectsty}` and `\allsectionsfont{\itshape}`

Comment: Or `\usepackage[it]{titlesec}`.